# How can I use different layouts in one module in Zend2

Tags: templates, layout, view, zend-framework2

How can I use different layouts in one module in Zend2
I write as in my code down and there is no effect
I need to use different layouts for different actions in one controller

```html
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    { $this->layout('layout/layout');
  $view = new ViewModel();
  $menu = new ViewModel();
  $menu->setTemplate('application/menu');
        $view->addChild($menu, 'menu');
    return $view;
    }
 
 public function portfolioAction()
    {
  $this->layout('layout/portfolio');
  $view = new ViewModel();
  $menu = new ViewModel();
  $menu->setTemplate('application/menu');
        $view->addChild($menu, 'menu');
    return $view;
    }
}
```

and this is my viewManager

```html
 'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
   'layout/portfolio'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout_portfolio.phtml',
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the layout is set up by the event MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH.
So I wrote a listener to change the layout. You can see my solution at https://github.com/dafap/DafapLayout and adapt it for your needs.